# HttpClient times out when redirected on a Post request [Mono/Xamarin]

Tags: c#, asp.net, mono, dotnet-httpclient

I've reported it as a bug here:
https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=30604

Which was reported before here:
https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=22384

The problem is that if you make a Post request to a server that replies with a redirection, HttpClient will time out. This problem doesn't happen if you use MS .NET, you have to run using [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/download/) (tested on Windows/Android/iOS)

Here is how to reproduce:

You need to have [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/download/) and [Xamarin Studio](http://xamarin.com/platform) or [MonoDevelop](http://www.monodevelop.com/download/) so that you can run the client console app using Mono.

Create a new ASP.NET project and add the following method to some controller (I use the default Home controller):

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult DeleteComment(int commentId)
    {
        return Redirect("/Home/Contact");
    }
```

Create a new Console project:

```
    var client = new HttpClient();
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:55141/"); // use the correct port
    client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10); // Doesn't have to be 10, just to save time. You can leave it as default

    var content1 = new StringContent("{\"commentid\":1}");
    content1.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");

    try {
        var r1 = client.PostAsync("/home/DeleteComment", content1).Result; // Change to your method url
        var test = r1.StatusCode;
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        return;
    }
```

This will:

- Be received and reply successfully on the server
- Throw an exception "Task was cancelled" in the console app.

Read more:

- http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/42410/bug-httpclient-times-out-when-redirected-on-a-post-request
- http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/42429/bug-report-httpclient-times-out-when-redirected-on-a-post-request

Comment: Reproduced here as well, mate. Hoping to find a solution.

Comment: Read my bug report, it's fixed

Comment: Yep, however, I am using the mono Docker image, which doesn't contain 4.2 yet. I'll see if I can simply create my own image instead.

Comment: Use ModernHttpClient a Xamarin component

Comment: I'm deploying Mono to Linux, not mobile, so don't have access to those native classes.

Comment: then you use this http://pastebin.com/J9k9jcHU

Comment: I ended up using a HttpClient library I found on Nuget: https://www.nuget.org/packages/HttpClient

Answer (score 0):

I know, this question is pretty old, but in case someone faces this with HttpClient, [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26931655/7741097) may help you.

```
HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
httpClient.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10);
```

Comment: you're saying it just needed to allow for more time?